# How to integrate Chromecast APIs in iOS?

Tags: ios, chromecast

I am going to integrate chromecast SDK into iOS, but here I am bit a confuse with receiver.html and whitelist email that exactly how to go with them.

So anyone please explain me regarding same.

Also tell me if it is compatible with any iOS Simulator instead of device.

Comment: look at doc https://developers.google.com/cast/chrome_sender

Comment: I have tried on simulator, it works as expect. You should build your iOS as sender and create one html app on Chromecast device as reciever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many developers successfully use the iOS simulator.  https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_2nd-screen_app_tutorial  for iOS and Android.

The Receiver is the HTML5 application that you create that runs on the Chromecast device.  Your iOS application talks to the [Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver), the Receiver will fetch your content from the internet based on the information that comes from your iOS application.